# Running an Apache Module before PHP

Tags: php, apache, apache-modules

I have been developing an Apache Module, and I need it to run before PHP does.

I tried registering the handler function using:

```
// Hook the main handler function to run before PHP5
static const char * const aszPos[]={ "mod_php5.c", NULL };
ap_hook_handler(cc_handler, NULL, aszPos, APR_HOOK_FIRST);
```

...but the page still comes out with the '`<?php ?>`' tags unparsed.

I am wondering if this is a hook issue, or if PHP is not parsing it because it doesn't recognize it as a PHP url, but I've tried calling it as, say:

`localhost/authCC/?url=http://www.google.pt/&req=name,nic,photo,TaxNo&token=12345`

...while having the correct 'LocationMatch' directive on 'mods-available/php5.conf', and it still won't parse.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on 2.4 - your C code looks fine (you used mod_heartbeat as the example?). I suspect that somehow PHP does not trigger as it sees no reason to. If you remove the module - does it then kick in as you'd expect ? On what (MIME, extension, location?). And your module does get ran (ap_log is your friend here) and it does not change/nullify something mod_php relies on (e.g. a mime type) to triger ?

Dw.

Comment: My module does definitely get ran, as it generates the page itself via  'ap_rputs' calls.
I do make a 'ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html;charset=utf-8");' call, and I have checked that 'php5.conf' has a 'SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source' directive for all '.php' files. 
Maybe this is the way, but where should I set it? On the 'r-handler' field?

Comment: No - it is a MIME type (albeit a funny one). So it goes in the (mime)headers.

Comment: Well, I decided to set it, using the 'ap_set_content_type()' function, but it didn't work.

After tinkering with the configuration files, I came to the conclusion that PHP WASN'T, in fact, running, because it only set itself as a handler for '.php' files. When I added the configuration directive, though, it refused to translate the PHP code I sent in the response, which I assume happens because PHP is now running before the module itself, since it is not logging anything.

What should I do now? Would it be wise to look into input filters? (I was using 'ap_rputs()' calls to output my page)

Comment: I running into the same problem. Did you finally found a solution ?